# Finding a concrete diff.eq solution of non-homogeneous eq. using homogeneous eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, problem-solving, cauchy-problem

I have three solutions:
$$y_1(x)=xsin(x)+3cos(x)$$
$$y_2(x)=(x+5)sin(x)$$
$$y_2(x)=(x+4)sin(x)$$

of the diff.eq:
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=g(x)$$

and the start condition:
$$y(0)=y'(0)=0$$

I need to solve this Initial Value Problem.
Now there are a lot of long ways to solve it, looking for a short one, but without any non-homogeneous formulas, because I've learned only homogeneous stuff.

I know that for homogeneous a general solution is a linear combination of the linear independent solutions, but I don't know if it is true for non-homogeneous (I think it's not, because there is non-zero on the right side of the eq.).

I probably could find $p,q$ and $g$, but that seems to be a long way and maybe unnecessary.
How should I solve this eq, i.e find the needed coefficient without solving non-homogeneous, but transforming it to a homogeneous eq. problem ?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a typo, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common term of the three solutions is $y_p(x)=x\sin x$, leaving $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ as homogeneous basis solutions. This means for the differential operator on the left side
$$
D^2+1=D^2+pD+q,
$$
so that $p=0$, $q=1$, $r=2\cos x$.

So the solution satisfying the initial condition is the identified particular solution
$$
y(x)=x\sin x.
$$

This all is looking for the most simple pattern, not the most rigorous treatment of the situation. There may be other solutions with non-constant coefficients, there may be a solution where the right side is zero,...

---

*More rigorous contemplations:*

The difference $y_3-y_2=\sin x$ is a homogeneous solution, thus any $x\sin x+c\sin x$ is also a solution.

After identifying $x\sin x$ as one of the possible inhomogenous/particular solutions, from the first equation one concludes that also $\cos x$ is a homogeous/complementary solution. Note that $x\sin x$ satisfies the initial conditions. Now as homogeneous solutions both
$$
0=-\sin x+p\cos x+q\sin x\\
0=-\cos x-p\sin x+q\cos x
$$
which as linear system has the unique solution $p=0$, $q=1$, constant for all $x$. Both homogeneous basis solutions have one non-zero value in value and derivative, so that they can not contribute to the initial conditions.

Comment: I'm trying to formalize it a little, but clearly I'm not familiar with this way of thinking about the differential as a variable with those power-alike rules, but intuitively it's seems to be correct. One thing I don't understand is about the conclusion from $a=0$ to the fact about the constants or $1-cos(x)$ thing. Actually I don't know what it means to solve a  non-homogeneous diff.eq from a higher order (than 1) with an initial values. 
I mean I have the solutions to the non-homogeneous eq.
In a homogeneous diff.eq I know I need to find the coefficients of the solutions by replacement.

Comment: So in homogeneous diff. eq of higher order I know that if $y_1(x), y_2(x)$ are solutions, then I need to find the $c_1, c_2$ in the $y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$, and with two conditions like $y(a)=b, y(c)=d$ it's easy.
What do I need to find here ? The general form of y, as you found at the end, with a parameter b ?
So there are two things I don't know: 
a. What it meant by solving this eq.
b. The conclusion of yours as i wrote at the first msg.

Comment: I just don't understand what do I need to find essentially ? I agree with what you wrote. 
Do I need to find $c_1,c_2, c_3$ such that: $y=c_1*xsinx +c_2*sinx+c_3$=2cos(x) ?
Because using the initial terms, I get $c_1 = 0$, $c_2 = 0$ and $c_3$ to be any value, but that just seems to be the solution to the non-homogeneous eq. ?

Comment: Not really, you get $y(x)=y_p(x)+C^Ty_h(x)$ if $y_h$ is the tuple of homogeneous basis solutions. There is no coefficient for the particular solution. Here that is $y(x)=x\sin x+c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x$. This $y$ has to satisfy the initial conditions. You can reconstruct the right side as $r=y''+y=y_p''+y_p$.